# MongoDB Aggregation in java: How to get total records count along with pagination result?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a search criteria in which I have to provide pagination on searched result along with total number of records in collection. Suppose in a collection of 10 records, I want to get only 5 records along with count of total records. The resulted data, I want to push them into separate object having count and searchResult properties. Total count of records will have to map to count and paginated records to searchResult. I have applied aggregation and it is working well except inclusion of CountOperation and ProjectOperation. When I add countOperation and ProjectOperation in aggregation it gives invalid reference "_id!" exception.
the expected query would be like this.

```
   db.customer.aggregate([
{
  $facet:{
    searchResult:[{$match:{"name" : { "$regex" : "xyz", "$options" : "i" }}}],
    count: [{ $count: 'count' }]
  }
}
```

])

and the output would be like this.

```
   [
    {
      "searchResult":[{...},{...},{...}, ...],
      "count":[{"count":100}]
    }
   ]
```

Search logic:

```
public List<SampleSearchResult> findListByRequest(ListRequest queryParams, Class<T> clazz) {

    String collectionName = mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(clazz);
    MatchOperation matchOperation = getMatchOperation(queryParams);
    SortOperation sortOperation = getSortOperation(queryParams);
    SkipOperation skipOperation = Aggregation.skip((long) queryParams.getPageNumber() * queryParams.getSize());
    LimitOperation limitOperation = Aggregation.limit(queryParams.getSize());
            CountOperation countOperation = Aggregation.count().as("count");
    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = getProjectionOperation();

    AggregationResults<SampleSearchResult> results = mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, sortOperation, skipOperation, limitOperation, countOperation, projectionOperation ), collectionName, SampleSearchResult.class);

    return (List<SampleSearchResult>) results.getMappedResults();
}
```

Projection operation logic

```
    private ProjectionOperation getProjectionOperation() {
    return Aggregation.project("count").and("_id").previousOperation();
}
```

SortOperation logic:

```
private SortOperation getSortOperation(ListRequest listRequest) {
    // setting defaults
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(listRequest.getSortBy())) {
        listRequest.setSortBy("_id");
        listRequest.setAsc(false);
    }
    Sort sort = listRequest.isAsc() ? new Sort(Direction.ASC, listRequest.getSortBy())
            : new Sort(Direction.DESC, listRequest.getSortBy());
    return Aggregation.sort(sort);
}
```

MatchOperation logic:

```
private MatchOperation getMatchOperation(ListRequest listRequest) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // build match operation logic with listRequest parameters
    return Aggregation.match(criteria);
}
```

The resultant object which will hold aggregation result

```
    public class SampleSearchResult {
private List<Object> searchResult;
private int count;
public List<Object> getSearchResult() {
    return searchResult;
}
public void setSearchResult(List<Object> searchResult) {
    this.searchResult = searchResult;
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

}

I need to write CountOperation and ProjectionOperation properly to map the data to SampleSearchResult but I'm not that efficient to do since I'm new to MongoDB opreations.

Comment: Questions:   What is the exclamation point `_id!`   ?   Is that really coming up on stderr?    Also:  you are saying
            `.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, sortOperation, skipOperation, limitOperation ), collectionName, SampleSearchResult.class);`
work but adding `countOperation, projectionOperation` does not?

Comment: yes, it's adding at the time of countOperation and projectOperation. The exclamation is coming up on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be coming very late, but let me drop my answer here for who ever might be having this same trouble in future. The right way to go is truly using facet as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

I could use the facet in Java, but mapping the result of the query to a pojo class was also a problem for me. But here is how I was able to get past that challenge.

First looking at the expected output as seen in the question:

```
   [
    {
      "searchResult":[{...},{...},{...}, ...],
      "count":[{"count":100}]
    }
   ]
```

A pojo to fit this output must be modelled like this:

```
@Getter //lombok stuff to create getters and setters
@Setter
public class CustomerSearchResult {

    private List<CustomerData> searchResult;
    private List<CountDto> count;
}
```

So here is **CountDto.java**

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class CountDto {
    private Long count;
}
```

And here is **CustomerData.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomerData {
    
    private Long dateCreated;
    private String Id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Next, MongoClient must be instantiated with a custom or default code registry like this:

```
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;

import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;

public class MongoSource {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MongoClient createClient(){
        String connectionString = "your.database.connection.string";
        ConnectionString connection = new ConnectionString(connectionString);

        CodecRegistry defaultCodec = MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        CodecRegistry fromProvider = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(defaultCodec, fromProvider);

        MongoClientSettings.Builder builder = MongoClientSettings.builder();
        builder.applyConnectionString(connection);
        MongoClientSettings settings = builder.codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).build();
        mongoClient =  MongoClients.create(settings);
        return mongoClient;
    }


    public MongoClient getMongoClient(){
        return mongoClient;
    }
}
```

**Using Mongo Java Driver 4.0.X**

Not sure the version of the mongo driver or third-party API that was used in the question but I think the use of criteria has been deprecated or was never part of mongo API natively. But this is how I was able to achieve this using the Mongo Java Driver 4.0.x

To achieve a search with paginated result and the total count, using facet, it would be required to build two separate pipelines

- One to do the search with sort, limit and skip
- The other to do the actual count of the total result without limit
  and skip

These two pipelines would finally be used to construct the facets to be used with the aggregate API.

Consider the pojo below used to define the respective query fields

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchQuery {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int pageNumber;
    int pageSize;
}
```

And here is the final snippet that performs the search and returns the CustomerSearchResult intsance that contains the count and the  paginated result defined by the **pageSize** and **pageNumber**.

```
import java.util.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.fields;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public CustomerSearchResult findListByRequest(SearchQuery queryParam){

        MongoSource mongoSource = new MongoSource();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoSource.createClient().getDatabase("customers_db");
        MongoCollection<CustomerSearchResult> collection = database.getCollection("customer", CustomerSearchResult.class);


        List<Bson> queryPipeline = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Bson> countPipeline = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Bson> andMatchFilter = new ArrayList<>();

        //you might want to check for null before using the fields in the query param object
        andMatchFilter.add(regex("firstName", Pattern.compile(queryParam.getFirstName(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));
        andMatchFilter.add(regex("lastName", Pattern.compile(queryParam.getLastName(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));

        if(queryParam.getPageNumber() == 0){
            queryParam.setPageNumber(1);
        }

        if(queryParam.getPageSize() == 0){
            queryParam.setPageSize(30);
        }

        queryPipeline.add(match(and(andMatchFilter)));
        queryPipeline.add(sort(eq("dateCreated", -1)));
        queryPipeline.add(skip(queryParam.getPageSize() * (queryParam.getPageNumber() - 1)));
        queryPipeline.add(limit(queryParam.getPageSize()));
        queryPipeline.add(project(fields(include("Id","firstName","lastName"))));

        countPipeline.add(match(and(andMatchFilter)));
        countPipeline.add(count());

        Facet resultFacet = new Facet("searchResult", queryPipeline);
        Facet totalDocFacet = new Facet("count", countPipeline);
        return collection.aggregate(Collections.singletonList(facet(resultFacet, totalDocFacet))).first();
    }
```

Note that the CustomerSearchResult fields are the same as the names given to the facets defined for each pipeline respectively. This will allow the defined coderegistry to map correctly the output document to your pojo class **(CustomerSearchResult)**

then with that you can do like so to access the count:

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new SearchQuery();
    searchQuery.setPageNumber(1);
    searchQuery.setPageSize(15);
    searchQuery.setFirstName("John");
    searchQuery.setLastName("Doe");
    CustomerSearchResult result = findListByRequest(query);
    long count = result.getCount()!= null? result.getCount().get(0).getCount() : 0;
    List<CustomerData> data = result.getSearchResult();
```